# Drupal taxonomy url alias in advanced taxonomy block

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-taxonomy

It seems that Advanced Taxonomy Block doesn't use a PathAuto url's.

Default setting of url is taxonomy/term/%tid.

Could somebody tell me replacement for term name?, instead of id I want to use taxonomy name.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Advanced Taxonomy Block for a specific reason? If all you're doing is linking to a term page (and not passing the term id to some custom view URL) you can probably use Taxonomy Menu  instead. Taxonomy Menu **will** use PathAuto URLs.

Check out http://chrisshattuck.com/blog/how-add-block-menu-tags-or-other-taxonomy-terms-drupal-site for a nice tutorial.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, but I have still problem with my seo friendly paths. In auto url alias config I have: grammar/category/[vocab-raw]/[catpath-raw] for one of my vocabulary. But in my taxonomy menu blocks my paths looks like this: /category/few-words-i-dont-know-from/die-präposition. I use default path set in my taxonomy menu fieldset in vocabulary edit form, when I try change this to vocabulary or hierarchy, my taxonomy block disappaer.

Comment: I changed my auto alias settings to category/grammar/[vocab-raw]/[catpath-raw] because I have a static page with grammar url, but I still have not good url's. The 'few-words-i-dont-know-from' in my current url's is my old vocab (delete) I have no idea why this old vocab name exists in my url's :(

Comment: In url alias I have cat-raw, not catpath-raw.

Comment: For D7 instead of `[catpath-raw]` you may try `[term:parents:join-path]/[term:name]`.